# Using DisplayPort results in screen flickering and blacking out

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xrandr, displayport

My computer is running Arch, and I would like to use a single monitor via DisplayPort. The configuration works fine with an HDMI cable, but is limited to 30 frames per second on a 3840x2160 resolution.

The hardware including the screen connected using a DisplayPort cable works properly when running Windows, so I'm not thinking about hardware issues.

With the HDMI cable, everything works out-of-the-box: I log into my system, and KDE plasma is started via `exec startplasma-x11` in the `.xinitrc`. If I connect the DisplayPort cable instead and then boot and login, I get flickering starting with the login window, and shortly after logging into my desktop the screen will turn black.

I did find a way to get the monitor to be connected via DP: Login with HDMI connected, open a separate virtual console using `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, change the cable, and do `xrandr --auto`, and then change back to the X login session. This way, the output is somewhat stable, but i still get flickering in the uppermost part of the screen (in particular with Electron apps such as Discord or Chrome, oddly).

The configuration that xrandr chooses in this workaround is the one I would like to use per default, but without the flickering and without having to do the cable-switching.

In this configuration, I have extracted the desired modeline via `cvt 3840 2160` to write an entry to `xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DisplayPort-1"
    Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "3840x2160_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "DisplayPort-1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "3840x2160_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "radeon"
EndSection
```

I have also added the line

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --primary --mode 3840x2160 --rate 60.00
```

to my `.xinitrc`.

Nevertheless, I have not gotten rid of the problems at startup yet.

How can I fix this? I am looking for a way to make my screen connect via DisplayPort on startup automatically. Is there a better way to do this?

---

Edit: my `journalctl -r` log looks like this (excerpt):

```
Jul 29 09:25:36 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
Jul 29 09:25:36 my_arch kded5[641]: bluedevil: ObexAgent registered
Jul 29 09:25:36 my_arch kded5[641]: bluedevil: ObexManager operational changed true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kded5[641]: Registering ":1.36/StatusNotifierItem" to system tray
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 86 : connected = true , enabled = true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 86 update 
                                                                   m_connected: 0 
                                                                   m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x557123179780) 
                                                                   CRTC: 79 
                                                                   MODE: 91 
                                                                   Connection: 0 
                                                                   Primary: true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 85 : connected = false , enabled = false
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 85 update 
                                                                   m_connected: 1 
                                                                   m_crtc QObject(0x0) 
                                                                   CRTC: 0 
                                                                   MODE: 0 
                                                                   Connection: 1 
                                                                   Primary: false
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 86 : connected = true , enabled = true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 86 update 
                                                                   m_connected: 0 
                                                                   m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x557123179780) 
                                                                   CRTC: 79 
                                                                   MODE: 91 
                                                                   Connection: 0 
                                                                   Primary: true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 85 : connected = false , enabled = false
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 85 update 
                                                                   m_connected: 1 
                                                                   m_crtc QObject(0x0) 
                                                                   CRTC: 0 
                                                                   MODE: 0 
                                                                   Connection: 1 
                                                                   Primary: false
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  1
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  91
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  79
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  86
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  1
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Disconnected"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  0
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  0
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  85
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  1016 571
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  3840 2160
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 0
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 1731
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 44040197
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  1
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Connected"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  91
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  79
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  86
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  1
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Disconnected"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  0
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  0
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  85
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetOutputPrimary 
                                                                   New primary: 86
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 86 update 
                                                                   m_connected: 0 
                                                                   m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x557123179780) 
                                                                   CRTC: 79 
                                                                   MODE: 91 
                                                                   Connection: 0 
                                                                   Primary: true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr:         Result:  0
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetCrtcConfig (change output) 
                                                                   Output: 86 ( "DisplayPort-1" ) 
                                                                   CRTC: 79 
                                                                   Pos: QPoint(0,0) 
                                                                   Mode: 91 KScreen::Mode(Id: "91" , Size: QSize(3840, 2160) @ 59.9809 ) 
                                                                   Rotation: 1
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr:         Enable outputs: false
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr:                  (86)
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change outputs: true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr:         Disable outputs: false
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change Screen Size: false
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr:                 Old: 85 
                                                                           New: 86
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform: 
                                                                   Primary Output: true
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  1
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(3840, 2160)
Jul 29 09:25:35 my_arch kscreen_backend_launcher[764]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
```

I'm wondering why my Monitor shows up with a rate of `59.9809` first. Could this be an issue?